# Cambiar titulo de columna en kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendoui

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el título de esta columna Kendo MVC Grid por medio de Javascript utilizando un botón de otra columna?

Esta es la columna a la que le quiero cambiar el título:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.segundo_nombre).Title("2do Nombre").Width(20);
```

Y este es el botón que quiero utilizar para cambiar el título:

```
columns.Command(commands => commands.Custom("Cambiar").Click("change"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Verás con los kendo, tampoco puedes hacer milagros, para poner un título en cada columna usa una sintaxis así:

```
    <div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ { field: "name", title: "Name" } ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</script>
```

Si quieres hacerlo desde una función usa el `detailTemplate` te dejo la información en este link : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-detailTemplate
Desde ahí puedes usar la información del dataSource en estas funciones y tratarlo a tu gusto.